# GeoServer error available fonts

Tags: geoserver

I have an issue on the available fonts on the installed GeoServer.

[image]

is a GeoServer with available fonts correctly installed.

[image]

is the GeoServer with the error.

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: can you tell us what else is different between the two machines?

Comment: Font interpretation is fully delegate to the Java runtime, which in turn can do it directly, or use system libraries. JDK version and operating system differences can play a significant role here.

Comment: thanks! two machines are similar.  I'm going to check again JDK version and operating system to find out what's going on